# Remove the text below the noteboard webpart when no post

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Is there any way to remove the text below the noteboard webpart when there is no comments?

"There are no notes posted yet. You can use notes to comment on a page, document, or external site. When you create notes they will appear here and for easy retrieval. Other people can also view the notes you post.

Right click or drag and drop this link to your browser's favorites or bookmarks toolbar to use notes to comment on external sites.
Click here for more information about this and other social networking features in Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010."

I tried the to remove using jquery with no sucess.

```
$('span.socialcomment-username > a').prop('onclick', '').unbind('click'); 

$('.socialcomment-username a').attr('onclick', '').unbind('click');
```

Answer (score 2):

You may consider using a timer job, because that text is set using JS and doesn't render on document ready. Here's a workaround I implemented.

```
var timer = SetInterval(setInterval,processComments, 2000);


function processComments() {
    if(!checkCommentsValid()) {


        // Hide empty note board message
        jQuery('.ms-socialCommentPaging ~ div:contains("There are no notes posted yet. You can use notes to comment on a page, document, or external site. When you create notes they will appear here and")').html(""); 


        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}


function checkCommentsValid() {

    var hideEmptyMessage = jQuery('.ms-socialCommentPaging ~ div:contains("There are no notes posted yet. You can use notes to comment on a page, document, or external site. When you create notes they will appear here and")').html() == "";
    return hideEmptyMessage;
}
```

Comment: The only limitation is that you will get a split second (depends how long you set the timer interval) of showing those lines before they disappear.

Comment: SharePoint provides a JavaScript array _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames and initialisation functions can be added to this array. By pushing a function onto the array, it will be called after the page is loaded. More info at http://stackoverflow.com/a/18199201/132599 - the post references InfoPath but is not specific to InfoPath. This avoids trying to set a timer interval that works.